# Drupal 8: How to get a user field image in template page.html.twig

Tags: image, drupal, twig

I want to display a users image in a topbar, defined in page.html.twig. 
The field is called "field_user_image" and is a field of user fields. 
I've set a default image, whicht should be taken, if the user is not logged in. When the user logs in, I want to pull the image, the user has set as his user image.

Is there any possibility to access the field_user_image in twig, on page.html.twig level?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

O.k., I just did it a bit unconventional. 
I created a view of user images in a block, filtered by currently logged in user. Then I rendered the block in page.html with twig tweak.

This surely isn't the prettiest way to do it, but it worked fast for me.

Comment: If it works, it works! There's more than one way to skin a cat :)